# MODULE_NOT_FOUND in heroku pg:backups

Tags: heroku, deployment

I've got problem with `heroku pg:backups capture --app myapp` command.

```
Heroku CLI submits usage information back to Heroku. If you would like to disable this, set `skip_analytics: true` in /home/ubuntu/.heroku/config.json
heroku-cli: Updating to 4.99.0-e5f5ef4... done
heroku-cli: Updating CLI...heroku-cli: Updating to 5.11.8-f58f4fa... done
Starting backup of postgresql-spherical-5948... done

Use Ctrl-C at any time to stop monitoring progress; the backup will continue running.
Use heroku pg:backups:info to check progress.
Stop a running backup with heroku pg:backups:cancel.

Backing up DATABASE to b598... pending
Backing up DATABASE to b598... !
 ▸    MODULE_NOT_FOUND: Cannot find module 'bytes'
```

Does anybody have similar problem? This command is launched with deploy on CircleCI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started running into the same problem yesterday and was finally able to come up with a solution that is working for me.

For starters, it looks like `bytes` is a dependency of `heroku-pg`, which is the part of Heroku CLI that is being used for the backups command. It seems like the dependency is not being included or installed with the version of heroku-cli that is being used to run the backup command.

I tried CircleCI’s “Rebuild with SSH” to troubleshoot the issue, and encountered similar error messages when attempting the backup command there. While trying to reinstall heroku-cli using npm, I found that the npm and node versions were way behind what heroku-cli wanted, so maybe that is part of the problem? Anyway, reinstalling with npm only produced an even more broken Heroku CLI.

Finally I checked the build environment and it was set to Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) which probably explains the way out of date npm/node packages. I changed it to Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) and pushed a new commit to CircleCI (A rebuild alone is not sufficient to change OS versions) and was able to successfully run the backup command that had been failing!

**Solution:** Set CircleCI build environment to Ubuntu 14.04